# Mapping of 2 objects(arrays) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapping

I have a javascript array with a tree structure like this

**Term, termguid**

```
  Term1, 1
      SubTerm1, 2
   Term2,  3
      Subterm2, 4
```

And another object like this:

**Term, termguid, listid**

```
Term1, 1, 1000
Subterm1, 2, 2000
Term2, 3, 3000
Subterm4, 4, 4000
```

I need to add the listid property to the first object based on the termguid.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction.

**Update 1:**

The first object is an array of arrays and its filled with this code:

```
function GetTermsDataFromTaxonomy(){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();           
    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);           
    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();           
    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_kl5tZjInn7STsFTzIE7n3Q==");          
    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("31da4bc1-6429-499a-9d5e-be5e18b13c87");         
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();          
    context.load(terms);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
            var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator(), tree = {
                term: terms,
                children: []
            };
            var termList = "Terms: \n";                 
            while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){                       
                var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current(); 
                var currentTermPath = currentTerm.get_pathOfTerm().split(';');
                var children = tree.children;

                 // Loop through each part of the path
                for (var i = 0; i < currentTermPath.length; i++) {
                    var foundNode = false;        
                    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                        if (children[j].name === currentTermPath[i]) {
                            foundNode = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Select the node, otherwise create a new one
                    var term = foundNode ? children[j] : { name: currentTermPath[i], children: [] };

                    // If we're a child element, add the term properties
                    if (i === currentTermPath.length - 1) {
                        term.term = currentTerm;
                        term.title = currentTerm.get_name();
                        term.guid = currentTerm.get_id().toString();
                    }

                    // If the node did exist, let's look there next iteration
                    if (foundNode) {
                        children = term.children;
                    }
                    // If the segment of path does not exist, create it
                    else {
                        children.push(term);

                        // Reset the children pointer to add there next iteration
                        if (i !== currentTermPath.length - 1) {
                            children = term.children;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
            localStorage.Terms = tree;
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            console.log('Execution time: ' + time);             
        },
            function(sender,args){          
              console.log(args.get_message());              
        });
}
```

The second list or array, I havent build it yet, but I know it will look like that.

Comment: What's your try and can you provide the data as is, I don't know what you're having, an array of objects or array of arrays?

Comment: Can you paste the code for the JavaScript array declarations?

Comment: please check the Update, that is the code to create the tree of arrays, or array of arrays, as you want to call it.